# How to store reference to a derived type in the base type reference?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Consider:

```
struct Base{};
struct Derived: Base{};

int main() {
    Derived *d{};
    Base *&b = d; // Error: non-const reference to rvalue. 
    (void)b; 
    return 0;
}
```

As the comment indicates, the assignment tries to store non-const reference to rvalue. I understand that the rvalue is the `d` converted to `Base *`. But how do I get around this problem, so I can change `d` by assigning to `b`?

Comment: I suspect that you wanted: `Derived d; Base& b = d;`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki No, I actually want pointers.

Comment: If that was allowed you could say `b = new Base;`. and `d` would point to an unrelated object.

Comment: Where exactly is the location of the memory used? Derived* d{}; creates a null pointer. What you can do, of course, would be Derived der; Derived* p_der = &der; Base* p_bas = p_der;, why not do that?

Comment: That is not assignment or initialization, that is *aliasing* and you can't *alias* a `Derived*` with a `Base*&`.

Comment: Is this a homework question where they want you to use virtual functions so that `Derived` can provide implementations of "set()" operations that are accessible through `Base`?

Comment: @Peter No it's not. The error occurred in real code. I distilled the issue to make a it a very simple (may be overly simplified) complete example.

Answer (score 1):

To demonstrate why its a problem, imagine you had another struct

```
struct OtherDerived : Base
{};
```

Now consider what would happen if you added the following line after your definition of b

```
b = new OtherDerived();
```

this (if allowed) would have to assign d (which is of type Derived*) to a OtherDerived*, which isn't valid since OtherDerived doesn't derive from Derive.

To solve this you could decide whether the pointer you are referencing actually needs to be a derived pointer. If not it can be a base pointer and your reference to a base pointer is then OK.

```
Derived *d{};
Base* pointerToABase = d;
Base*& refToAPointerToABase = pointerToABase;
```

Otherwise if the pointer you reference must be a Derived* not a Base* then can you change the type of your reference : e.g. replace the declaration of b with.

```
    Derived*& refToAPointerToADerived = d;
```

I am aware that this isn't what you actually ask for in the title of the question - but as described you can't do that anyway.

Without knowing why you need a reference to the pointer its hard to suggest an alternative approach.